# Code snippet is extending past border. How to make it responsive for mobile view?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using nextjs to display the content from ghost but I noticed this offset when dealing with code blocks/snippets. How do I fix this so it's responsive for mobile?

[image]

And this is how it looks without the code block:

[image]

I've applied `white-space: pre-wrap;` and it works for small code tags but not big ones.

Because I'm using ghost content api and pulling in the html it's difficult to make changes.

I import the html from ghost and render it like so:

```
<Text
   lineHeight="10"
   fontSize="2xl"
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }}
 ></Text>
```

I have that wrapped in a container and I'm modifying the tags like so:

```
<>
      <style jsx global>{`
        pre {
          display: block;
          font-family: monospace;
          white-space: pre;
          margin: 1em 0px;
        }
        code {
          color: #fff;
          text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
          font-family: Menlo, Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
          direction: ltr;
          text-align: left;
          word-spacing: normal;
          word-wrap: normal;
          line-height: 1.4;
          background: none;
          border: 0;
          tab-size: 4;
          hyphens: none;
          overflow-wrap: break-word;
          white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
      `}</style>
      <Flex
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        bg={bgColor[colorMode]}
        color={color[colorMode]}
      >
        <DarkModeSwitch />
        <Flex alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" pt="10">
          {children}
        </Flex>
      </Flex>
    </>
```

I've copied everything in Matt Carlotta example but I'm still getting this result:

[image]

However when I inspect his example I get this:

[image]

Which I'm able to scroll to the right in order to view the full code.

I'm guessing the syntax highlighter is helping with this. However because I'm importing the html that ghost generates I'm not able to apply that. Or if I am I'm not sure how.

**Solution** was to apply the changes recommended by Matt Carlotta and adjust the font size of the code tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Use `white-space: pre-wrap;` with `overflow-wrap: break-word`;

Working example (in this case `wrapLongLines` = `white-space: pre-wrap;`):

[image: Edit Syntax Highlighter Break Word]

I'm not sure if you're just throwing this into a `pre`/`code` block, but you'll get more flexibility and options with a [syntax highlighter](https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter). Even the reactjs documentation runs into [similar issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWbp5.png).

Yet, dealing with small screen sizes will always result in mangled code unless you set `overflow-y: auto;` with a `width`/`max-width`/`min-width` attribute.

Comment: I've tried the overflow-wrap: break-word but no change. I would gladly use the syntax highlighter but because I'm pulling in the html from ghost I can't wrap anything up. I'm using <style jsx global> to modify the tags. I will edit my question and show you the code.

Comment: Fork this codesandbox repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-jsx-example-suwv6 and modify it with your exact code (just include the code required to reproduce the problem and fake any data that comes back from ghost -- in other words, make it a static data object/string or however it's structured). Once done, share the codesandbox link here.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by simply modifying the font-size to 70% for the code tag. I'm using chakra ui and when I started modifying the code from their Text component to a div to show you in codesandbox I noticed the error stopped happening because I'm not applying the fontsize modifier. When I modify the font-size with your example to a larger size it occurs as well. This may be a weird solution but it works for me haha.

Appreciate all your help and the added styling you showed me in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto`, also wrap your `<code>` in a `<pre>` if not already.